# Use attributes of preceding estimators as parameters in ML pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

I am using `Pipelines` from Pyspark's `ML` library to preprocess text and calculate the **TF-IDF** values for all tokens. I also created a custom `Transformer` that returns for each text snippet the 5 tokens with the highest TF-IDF values. The main code looks like this:

```
%pyspark
tokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="tokenized", pattern="\\W")
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="tokenized", outputCol="filtered")
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="count", vocabSize=pow(2,10))
idf = IDF(inputCol="count", outputCol="TF-IDF")
normalizer = Normalizer(inputCol="TF-IDF", outputCol="normalized", p=2.0)
top_token_extractor = TopTokenExtractor(inputCol="normalized", outputCol="topTokens", vocabulary=model.stages[2].vocabulary) # !!! does not work

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, remover, count_vectorizer, idf, normalizer, top_token_extractor])

model = pipeline.fit(df)
```

And here is the implementation of `TopTokenExtractor`:

```
%pyspark
from pyspark import keyword_only
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Transformer 
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, Param 
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

class TopTokenExtractor(Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol): 

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, vocabulary=None): 
        super(TopTokenExtractor, self).__init__() 
        self.vocabulary = Param(self, "vocabulary", "")
        self._setDefault(vocabulary=set())
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs 
        self.setParams(**kwargs) 

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, vocabulary=None): 
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs 
        return self._set(**kwargs) 

    def setVocabulary(self, value):
        self._paramMap[self.vocabulary] = value
        return self

    def getVocabulary(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.vocabulary)

    def _transform(self, dataset): 
        out_col = self.getOutputCol() 
        in_col = dataset[self.getInputCol()]
        vocabulary = self.getVocabulary()

        def f(s): 
            token_tuples = sorted(list(zip(s.indices, s.values)), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
            top_tokens = list()
            for i in range(0, min(5, len(token_tuples))):
                top_tokens.append(vocabulary[token_tuples[i][0]])
            return top_tokens

        t = ArrayType(StringType()) 
        return dataset.withColumn(out_col, udf(f, t)(in_col))
```

The problem is that in order to return a list of tokens rather than indices, I need to pass the vocabulary from the `CountVectorizer` as a parameter to `TopTokenExtractor`. After calling `pipeline.fit(df)` the vocabulary could be accessed by `model.stages[2].vocabulary`, but I could not figure out how to pass it as a parameter in the course of a pipeline. Is this possible at all?

As a workaround, I might split up the pipeline into two parts, but I would really prefer to have a single pipeline if possible.

Comment: TL;DR You cannot reference something that doesn't exist yet. For longer answer: include implementation of `TopTokenExtractor` (or point to the one, if it is a library function).

Comment: Well, the input column "normalized" does not exist at the moment of the initialization of `TopTokenExtractor` yet either... If the `vocabulary` was lazily evaluated and I could pass a reference to the `Estimator` attribute rather than the list itself it would facilitate things a lot, but I guess that is not possible.

Comment: It is a big chunk of code, most of which is identical to the custom `Transformer` implementations you can find in many other threads. But if you insist...

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I posted the implementation above and would have hoped to get the promised answer.